# Library Paths Delphi Rio

Tags: search, path

I've installed Delphi RIO and when I add paths to the Library search path, it doesn't recognize the paths I enter.  I'm being forced to add all the modules to my project in order to get it to see the files.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you add library paths to the win32 environment and your project compiles to 64 bit, or visa versa?

Comment: Search path problems can be easily debugged by running the free tool procmon (proces monitor) from the Sysinternals suite. Apply a filter on process names bds.exe and dcc32.exe and let it capture file events. Build your application and you'll see all file acces by Delphi in the live log, even failures like path not found.